# lapply if some input values in a list are NULL

Tags: r, list, matrix, lapply

I have a list with matrices of different sizes that looks like this:

```
> MDP$B
     [,1]       [,2]       [,3]       [,4]      
[1,] numeric,4  NULL       NULL       NULL      
[2,] numeric,16 numeric,16 numeric,16 numeric,16
```

The following works with previous lists and also works, if I only apply it to e.g. [[1,1]] in the upper list, so the NULL values are the problem.

```
if(isfield(MDP,"b")){              
  MDP$b = lapply(MDP$b,col_norm)  
} else{
  MDP$b = lapply(MDP$B,col_norm)
}
```

The function col_norm looks like this and normalizes colum vectors:

```
col_norm = function(x){t(t(x)/colSums(x))}
```

I get the error x must be numeric. Is there a way to make lapply just skip the NULL values? OR is it possible to fully delete [1,2],[1,3] and [1,4], so that the problem can`t occur?

NOTE: it was supposeds to say isfield(MDP, "b") not "b1", sorry for confusion.

SOLUTION BY @Roland:
You can always use an anonymous function function(x) if (!is.null(x)) col_norm(x) else NULL. –
Roland

Final line looks like this:

```
MDP$B = lapply(MDP$B,function(x) if (!is.null(x)) col_norm(x) else NULL)
```

I had to redim the list with "dim(MDP$B) = matrix(c(2,4))", but thats fine :))

dim(MDP$B) = matrix(c(2,4))

SOLUTION TO THAT also by @Roland: use:
MDP$b[] <- lapply(MDP$b, (x) if (!is.null(x)) col_norm(x) else NULL)

Comment: Sometimes it's `B` and sometimes `b`? You can always use an anonymous function `function(x) if (!is.null(x)) col_norm(x) else NULL`.

Comment: How could I implement such an anonymous function?

Comment: My code shows how to implement this? Just replace `col_norm` with this code in your `lapply` call.

Comment: And concerning B and b: the upper says: if there is a "b" in a list than do col_norm on it. If not given, it will create a MDP$b out of MDP$B. MDP$B is normalized in another line in the script, but using the same col_norm function. It is a conversion of some matlab code I am doing...

Comment: @Roland WORKED! Thanks!! I will have to put it back into a matrix list shape, but other than that he did it :)) Thanks a lot!

Comment: Try `MDP$b[] <- lapply(MDP$b, \(x) if (!is.null(x)) col_norm(x) else NULL)`. That should preserve the matrix structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create an anonymous function that checks if it is passed `NULL`. You also may want to use `[<-` instead of `=` to assign into the matrix and preserve its class and dimensions. Both together:

```
MDP$b[] <- lapply(MDP$b, \(x) if (!is.null(x)) col_norm(x) else NULL)
```

Answer (score 0):

In `colSums` function there is a `na.rm` parameter:

```
col_norm = function(x){t(t(x)/colSums(x, na.rm=TRUE))}
```

Or if they are `NULL`, also do:

```
col_norm = function(x){t(t(x)/colSums(replace(x, NULL, NA), na.rm=TRUE))}
```

Comment: OP doesnot have `NA` values. They have `NULL`.

Comment: @Roland Edited mine

Comment: Yes, it didn't solve the problem yet :// A little background: the upper list is a conversion of some Matlab code working with cell structures. I use lists for that which works fine. Just the B-matrices, I put them in the upper list and just left parts of the dimension empty.... Maybe there is another way to list the upper matrices....

Comment: @SteffenSchwerdtfeger Why does it not? Try `col_norm = function(x){t(t(x)/colSums(replace(x, 'NULL', NA), na.rm=TRUE))}`

Comment: It says  "Error in colSums(replace(x, NULL, NA), na.rm = TRUE) : 
  'x' must be numeric". Works fine with the other lists and again if I process MDP$B[[1,1]], but still not with MDP$B unfortunately.

Comment: @SteffenSchwerdtfeger `col_norm = function(x){t(t(as.numeric(x))/colSums(as.numeric(replace(x, 'NULL', NA)), na.rm=TRUE))}`

Comment: + in the if/else argumentation above it returns " Error in t.default(x) : argument is not a matrix"

Comment: `col_norm = function(x){t(t(as.matrix(as.numeric(x)))/colSums(as.numeric(replace(x, 'NULL', NA)), na.rm=TRUE))}`

Comment: @SteffenSchwerdtfeger ^

Comment: Made it all worse, unfortunatly, as it now always returns x must be array of at least two dimensions...

Comment: @SteffenSchwerdtfeger Please use my suggestion instead of following U12 into the rabbit hole.