# How to stop lapply and formatC functions from processing NULL values in data table?

Tags: r, shiny, null, format, lapply

I'm trying to iron out a formatting bug. My `formatC()` function applied against a data frame, using `lapply()`, is adding a decimal point to NULL values in the data frame output column header. I do want to keep the NULL values appearing in my output column header, I just don't want a "." added to the end of each NULL output in the column header. That combination of `lapply()` and `formatC()` is important for formatting the numeric values in the data frame (though in the below reproducible code they are not produced, for the sake of brevity). Please see image at the bottom where you can see the issue.

I've tried following the advice from [lapply if some input values in a list are NULL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69582994/lapply-if-some-input-values-in-a-list-are-null) but it hasn't worked for me yet.

So how can I prevent "lapplying" `formatC()` to NULL elements? Leave the NULLs alone.

Below is seriously-gutted code that shows the offending code in a single line immediately below the line `# commenting-out the below line removes the "." from the NULL` (the other 2 commented-out lines are my attempts to resolve) and produces the output shown in the image, illustrating only the problem at hand:

```
library(data.table)
library(dplyr)
library(DT)
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)

transitDF <- 
  as.data.frame(
    data.table(
      ID = as.numeric(c("1930145","1930145","1930145","1930145","1930145")),
      Period_1 = as.numeric(c("1","2","3","4","5")),
      Period_2 = c("2012-10","2012-11","2012-12","2013-01","2013-02"),
      Values = as.numeric(c("8","17.97","97.85","87.85","273.85")),
      State = c("NULL","NULL","NULL","NULL","NULL")
    )
  )  

num_transit <- function(x,from,to,refvar="Period_2", return_matrix=T) {
  res <- x[get(refvar) %in% c(to,from), if(.N>1) .SD, by=ID, .SDcols = c(refvar, "State")]
  res <- res[, id:=1:.N, by=ID]
  res <- dcast(res, ID~id, value.var="State")[,.N, .(`1`,`2`)]
  setnames(res,c("from","to", "ct"))
  if(return_matrix) return(convert_transits_to_matrix(res, unique(x$State)))
  res
}

convert_transits_to_matrix <- function(transits,states) {
  m = matrix(NA, nrow=length(states), ncol=length(states), dimnames=list(states,states))
  m[as.matrix(transits[,.(to,from)])] <- transits[[3]] 
  m = data.table(m)[,to_state:=rownames(m)]
  setcolorder(m,"to_state")
  return(m[])
}

ui <- fluidPage(DTOutput("resultstransitDF"))

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  results <- 
    reactive({
      setDT(transitDF)
      results <- num_transit(transitDF,1,2,"Period_1")
      results <- cbind(results, Sum = rowSums(results[,-1])) 
    
    # commenting-out the below line removes the "." from the NULL
      results[] <- as.data.frame(lapply(results, formatC, decimal.mark ="."))
      
    # results[] <- as.data.frame(lapply(results, function(x) if (!is.null(x)) (formatC, decimal.mark =".") else NULL))
    # results[] <- as.data.frame(lapply(if(!is.null(results)), formatC, decimal.mark ="."))
            
    })
  
  output$resultstransitDF <- renderDT(server=FALSE, {datatable(data = results())})
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Output when running the above:

[image]

Comment: I didn't follow everything, but it seems to me that you could define a conditional version of the ***formatC*** function or use ***purrr::map_if*** instead of ***lapply***.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry for my comment, I didn't understand the issue. In fact this has nothing to do with `formatC`, which anyway is not applied to the column names. The problem is with the usage of `"NULL"` as the name of a list component, and `as.data.frame` "corrects" this name by default.

```
> m <- matrix(1, nrow=1, ncol=1, dimnames=list("NULL", "NULL"))
> m # ok
     NULL
NULL    1
> data.table(m) # ok
   NULL
1:    1
> as.data.frame(data.table(m)) # ok
  NULL
1    1
> as.data.frame(lapply(data.table(m), formatC)) # not ok
  NULL.
1     1
> data.frame("NULL" = 4) # the problem is here: the "NULL" string is reserved
  NULL.
1     4
> lapply(data.table(m), formatC) # look, the name is the NULL object, not the "NULL" string
$`NULL`
[1] "1"
> # you can solve the problem as follows:
> as.data.frame(lapply(data.table(m), formatC), check.names = FALSE)
  NULL
1    1
```

Comment: Hi Stéphane, thank you! And thanks for the step-by-step instructions. Funny that you answered, after a long time of not hearing from you, because as I worked on this posted code & whacked it way back to the point of nonsensical output (other than "NULL." issue), I thought about your comment when I first started with Stack that I should post the bare minimum code, because I was posting long confusing code. I could have cut further too, dropping Shiny for example.